# Connectedness of the difference of two open sets

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, algebraic-topology

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two connected open sets in $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that the closure of $Y$ is included in $X$. Can we say that $X\setminus Y$ is connected?

If $n=1$, the result is obviously false. We can take for $X$ and $Y$ any two intervals. But it seems the result is correct for $n>1$. Here is what I did: I assume $X\setminus Y$ is a disjoint union of two open sets $A$ and $B$ in $X\setminus Y$, and then $X=(Y\cup A)\cup B$. This union is disjoint and I can show that $Y\cup A$ is open in $X$, but not $B$.

Comment: Hint: Projection maps $x \mapsto x_i$ are continuous.  Using this, the result from $n=1$ applies to any $n$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No for every $n\ge 1$. For $n\ge 2$ consider $X=B(0,2)$ and $Y=B(0,1)\setminus \{0\}$.